# Take maximum of multiple function calls

Tags: kotlin, collections, max

Let's say I have the function `fun someValue() : Double`.
I want to run this function *n* times and take the maximum of all the results.

I know I can safe it all in a list and use `max()`, but I don't want to waste that space (because it actually returns a bigger object).

Does there exist a library-function for this?

Maybe something like `repeat(n){someValue()}.max()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways that don't allocate an intermediate array or list of all the values.

```
var x = someValue()
repeat(n - 1) {
    x = max(x, someValue())
}

val y = (1 until n).fold(someValue()) { acc, _ -> max(acc, someValue()) }
```

Comment: shouldn't there be n-1 because of init calls?

Comment: another solution `val maxValue = generateSequence { someValue() }.take(n).max()`